# Groupby, sort within groups, and aggregate the sorted data

Tags: pyspark, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table `data` containing three columns: `id`, `time`, and `text`. Rows with the same `id` comprise the same long text ordered by `time`. The goal is to group by `id`, order by `time`, and then aggregate them (concatenate all the `text`). I am using PySpark.

I can get the order of elements within groups using a window function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

w = W.partitionBy(F.col('id')).orderBy(F.col('time').asc())
(
    data
    .withColumn('text_num', F.row_number().over(w))
)
```

I can also concatenate the texts by group, but this does not guarantee the order:

```py
(
    data
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(F.concat_ws(' ', F.collect_list(F.col('text'))).alias('concat_text'))
)
```

How do I groupby, sort within groups, and then aggregate the sorted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
data = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 1, 'str1'), ('a', 2, 'str2')],
    schema=['id', 'time', 'text']
)

data.printSchema()
data.show(1, False)
+---+----+----+
|id |time|text|
+---+----+----+
|a  |1   |str1|
+---+----+----+
```

You can use the `collect_list` to collect the element of each group in sequence and select the max group:

```
data.withColumn(
    'text_lst', func.collect_list('text').over(Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(func.asc('time')))
).groupBy(
    'id'
).agg(
    func.concat_ws('-', func.max('text_lst')).alias('text_concat')
).show(
    10, False
)
+---+-----------+
|id |text_concat|
+---+-----------+
|a  |str1-str2  |
+---+-----------+
```

---

Edit 1: another solution without using the `max`
If you don't want to collect all the text list, you can use the `struct` to construct a new column with `time` and `text` column:

```
data.withColumn(
    'struct', func.struct('time', 'text')
).groupBy(
    'id'
).agg(
    func.array_sort(func.collect_list(func.col('struct'))).alias('sort_array')
).withColumn(
    'text_concat', func.concat_ws('-', func.col('sort_array').getItem('text'))
).show(
    10, False
)
+---+----------------------+-----------+
|id |sort_array            |text_concat|
+---+----------------------+-----------+
|a  |[{1, str1}, {2, str2}]|str1-str2  |
+---+----------------------+-----------+
```

As you collect the list of struct and perform the array sorting, it will sort the column based on the first field of the struct. After sorting, you can extract the field in struct to perform concatenation.

Comment: This works, thank you. But isn't it wasteful to collect all text lists to get just the longest?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a struct of `time` & `text`, collect that to an array and sort that array using `array_sort`. `array_sort` will sort based on first element of the structs which is `time` in your case.

here's an example

```py
# input - data_sdf
# +---+----------+---+
# | id|      time|txt|
# +---+----------+---+
# |  1|2023-09-01|foo|
# |  1|2023-09-03|bar|
# |  1|2023-09-02|baz|
# +---+----------+---+

data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.array_sort(func.collect_list(func.struct('time', 'txt'))).alias('txt_list')). \
    withColumn('concat_txt', func.concat_ws(' ', func.transform('txt_list', lambda x: x.txt))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
# |id |txt_list                                                 |concat_txt |
# +---+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
# |1  |[{2023-09-01, foo}, {2023-09-02, baz}, {2023-09-03, bar}]|foo baz bar|
# +---+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```